# Python datetime bug?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, python-datetime

Ok, I am at a loss here. Is there any reason why an hour seems to be arbitrarily added to the date when converting to a timestamp and then converting back from a timestamp?

```
import datetime
dt = datetime.datetime(year=2020, month=3, day=8, hour=2)
print(dt)
dt2 = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(dt.timestamp())
print(dt2)
```

The output is:

```
2020-03-08 02:00:00
2020-03-08 03:00:00
```

HUH?
Tested on 3.10.4 and 3.10.3

Comment: This is EST timezone btw, I'm not sure if that matters. It doesn't seem to happen with other dates.

Comment: Python 's naive datetime representing local time can be pretty confusing - this is just another example I think. Try to initialize dt with the appropriate time zone and see what happens... in general, use aware datetime (tz set) if you can, to avoid such confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works fine on my computer, which is in Adelaide (Australia). The reason it doesn't on yours is that Daylight Savings time for the US EST time zone commenced on March 8th 2020, and so the clock switched forward from 2am to 3am at that time and thus the timestamp generated for 2am corresponds to an actual time of 3am (since 2am doesn't actually exist). If you try your code with `hour=1` or `hour=3` it will work fine.

You can resolve this issue by working solely with UTC time.

Comment: Thank you. Maybe I'm dumb, I don't think I would have figured that out.

Comment: @RyanMcconnell I've seen the issue a few times before in other environments so I recognised it pretty quickly. Just a matter of experience.

Comment: If I were to switch all the code to use UTC instead of the localized time, the daylight savings issue should theoretically disappear right?

Comment: @RyanMcconnell Correct.